Upper bound for the trace of matrix product
I was following this video, where it is stated:
For $\mathbf{W} \in \mathrm{R}^{n\times m}$, $\mathbf{M} \in \mathrm{R}^{n\times m}$ and for $\mathbf{\Lambda}\in \mathrm{R}^{m\times m}$ which is diagonal, positive definite with no zeros on the diagonal, the following inequality holds
$$-2\ \textrm{tr}(\mathbf{W}^{T}\mathbf{M}\mathbf{\Lambda}) \le a\ \textrm{tr}(\mathbf{W}^{T}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{\Lambda}) + \frac{1}{a}\ \textrm{tr}(\mathbf{M}^{T}\mathbf{M}\mathbf{\Lambda})$$
where a is positive scalar.
I've been struggling to understand this inequality. The author mentions Young's inequality applied to the trace operator but I couldn't find an explanation for it in the literature. Could someone help explain why it holds, and if possible, point me to a reference? I'd really appreciate it.

This follows from $\mathrm{tr}[(aW+M) \Lambda (aW+M)^T] \ge 0$.

Can you clarify which left-hand side expression properties you used to obtain that equation?

All you need are the basic properties of trace: (1) cyclicity, (2) linearity, and (3) trace of transpose of a matrix is equal to the trace of the matrix.
